# Representing multiple real values by a single real value

Tags: math, statistics, average, scaling

I have a set of real numbers in the range [0,1], I want to find a single value to represent them, however, this value should be also in the range [0,1].I don't want to use average as it's sensitive to extreme values. What can I use instead? Can I sum them then scale the summation to the range [0,1]? Notice however, that in my case the scaling rule (x-min)/(max-min) gives the same result as average.. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Your question really needs to be made more specific. Whatever measure you select depends upon it relation to the data and what you intend to use this number for. As jcoppens says, there is a multitude of single values that can represent this range - but only a very small subset would make any sense, or be useful for further analysis. To decide what that subset is, you need to specify (at least) points 1 and 2 above. See this, as a start http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC137399/

Comment: The median might do. This is less sensitive to extreme value.

Answer (score 2):

You should really look at some basic information on statistics! And decide which information is important to you.

> Can I sum them then scale the summation to the range [0,1]?

is in fact the definition of the average value. You should consider the actual meaning of the data, and then check if average, or RMS (Root Mean Square), Standard deviation  or something else could be valid abstractions of the original dataset. In some cases, average values become useful if you just discard, say, 1% of values which are extreme.